# What is the best datatype for storing URLs in a POSTGRESSQL database IN RAILS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

What is the best datatype for storing URLs in a POSTGRESSQL database IN RAILS ?

url can be youtube video link or some website links.

Comment: You could create a domain over `text` with a check constraint that ascertains valid syntax.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Datatype depends upon the length of your URL. 
If your url fits in 255 characters(which is default max limit set by rails in migration for string column), you can use `string` datatype(varchar in Postgresql). 
If you think, your urls can be greater than 255 characters, then blindly go for `text`, it will fit all urls.

Comment: In case you're finding this like me down the road, note that as far back as 9.1 (probably farther back) the official documentation suggests defaulting to TEXT unless you have a reason to limit the number of characters in columns (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-character.html):

Comment: Tip: There is no performance difference among these three types, apart from increased storage space when using the blank-padded type, and a few extra CPU cycles to check the length when storing into a length-constrained column. While character(n) has performance advantages in some other database systems, there is no such advantage in PostgreSQL; in fact character(n) is usually the slowest of the three because of its additional storage costs. In most situations text or character varying should be used instead.

Answer (score 1):

I personally see no reason not to store them as a `varchar` as they will allow for any length URL.

If you're using migrations, you can use the `string` data type to achieve this.

```
rails g migration CreateURLStorage url:string
```